# Add a All times record and a session record to a js snake game

Tags: javascript

i have created a snake game using javascript with the normal score showing in every moment, but now i need to add an all time record score and a session score using sessionStorage and localStorage, but i dont know how to actually do that, can someone help? Sorry for some thing being in spanish.

This is the code i have:

```
const KEY_ENTER=13;
const KEY_LEFT=37;
const KEY_UP=38;
const KEY_RIGHT=39;
const KEY_DOWN=40;
const KEY_P=80;

const ARRIBA=0;
const DERECHA=1;
const ABAJO=2;
const IZQUIERDA=3;

var lienzo=null, canvas=null;
var body=[];
var food=new Rectangle(80,80,10,10,"#f00");
var wall=[];
wall.push(new Rectangle(100,50,10,10, "#999"));
wall.push(new Rectangle(100,100,10,10, "#999"));
wall.push(new Rectangle(200,50,10,10, "#999"));
wall.push(new Rectangle(200,100,10,10, "#999"));
var score=0;
var RecordSesion=0;
var RecordAbsoluto=0;
var lastPress=null;
var dir=DERECHA;
var pause=false;
var gameover=true;
var numMediosCargados = 0;

var medios = [];
medios['iBody'] = new Image();
medios['iBody'].src='imgs/body.png';
medios['iBody'].addEventListener("load", cargaMedio, false);
medios['iFood'] = new Image();
medios['iFood'].src='imgs/fruit.png';
medios['iFood'].addEventListener("load", cargaMedio, false);
medios['iWall'] = new Image();
medios['iWall'].src='imgs/wall.png';
medios['iWall'].addEventListener("load", cargaMedio, false);
medios['aComer'] = new Audio();
medios['aMorir'] = new Audio();

if(canPlayOgg())
{
    medios['aComer'].src="sounds/chomp.ogg";
    medios['aMorir'].src='sounds/dies.ogg';
}
else
{
    medios['aComer'].src="sounds/chomp.m4a";
    medios['aMorir'].src='sounds/dies.m4a';
}

medios['aComer'].addEventListener("canplaythrough", cargaMedio, false);
medios['aMorir'].addEventListener("canplaythrough", cargaMedio, false);


function cargaMedio()
{
    numMediosCargados++;
}

function iniciar()
{
    canvas=document.getElementById('lienzo');
    lienzo=canvas.getContext('2d');

    if (numMediosCargados == Array.longitud(medios))
    {
        run();
        repaint();
    }
    else
    {
        cargando();
    }
} 

function cargando()
{
    if (numMediosCargados < Array.longitud(medios))
    {
        lienzo.fillStyle="#fff";
        lienzo.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        lienzo.fillStyle="#0f0";
        lienzo.fillText('Cargando '+numMediosCargados+' de '+Array.longitud(medios),10,10);
        setTimeout(cargando, 100);
    }
    else
    {
        iniciar();
    }
}

function run()
{
    setTimeout(run,50);
    act();
}

function repaint(){
    requestAnimationFrame(repaint);
    paint(lienzo);
}

function act()
{
    if (!pause && !gameover)
    {
        for(var i=body.length-1;i>0;i--)
        {
            body[i].x=body[i-1].x;
            body[i].y=body[i-1].y;
        }

        if(lastPress==KEY_UP && dir != ABAJO)
            dir=ARRIBA;
        if(lastPress==KEY_RIGHT && dir!= IZQUIERDA)
            dir=DERECHA;
        if(lastPress==KEY_DOWN && dir!=ARRIBA)
            dir=ABAJO;
        if(lastPress==KEY_LEFT && dir!=DERECHA)
            dir=IZQUIERDA;

        if(dir==DERECHA)
            body[0].x+=10;
        if(dir==IZQUIERDA)
            body[0].x-=10;
        if(dir==ARRIBA)
            body[0].y-=10;
        if(dir==ABAJO)
            body[0].y+=10;

        if(body[0].x>=canvas.width)
            body[0].x=0;
        if(body[0].y>=canvas.height)
            body[0].y=0;
        if(body[0].x<0)
            body[0].x=canvas.width-10;
        if(body[0].y<0)
            body[0].y=canvas.height-10;

        for(var i=0;i<wall.length;i++)
        {
            var dirWall = random(4);

            if(dirWall==DERECHA)
                wall[i].x+=10;
            if(dirWall==IZQUIERDA)
                wall[i].x-=10;
            if(dirWall==ARRIBA)
                wall[i].y-=10;
            if(dirWall==ABAJO)
                wall[i].y+=10;

            if(wall[i].x>=canvas.width)
                wall[i].x=0;
            if(wall[i].y>=canvas.height)
                wall[i].y=0;
            if(wall[i].x<0)
                wall[i].x=canvas.width-10;
            if(wall[i].y<0)
                wall[i].y=canvas.height-10;
        }           

        if(body[0].intersects(food))
        {
            medios['aComer'].play();
            body.push(new Rectangle(0,0,10,10, "#0f0"));
            score++;
            food.x=random(canvas.width/10-1)*10;
            food.y=random(canvas.height/10-1)*10;
        }

        for(var i=2;i<body.length;i++)
        {
            if(body[0].intersects(body[i]))
            {
                medios['aMorir'].play();
                gameover=true;
            }
        }

        for(var i=0;i<wall.length;i++)
        {
            if(food.intersects(wall[i]))
            {
                food.x=random(canvas.width/10-1)*10;
                food.y=random(canvas.height/10-1)*10;
            }

            for (var j = 0;j < body.length;j++)
            {
                if(body[j].intersects(wall[i]))
                {
                    medios['aMorir'].play();
                    gameover=true;
                }
            }
       }

    }

    if(lastPress==KEY_P)
    {
        pause=!pause;
        lastPress=null;
    }

    if (gameover && lastPress==KEY_ENTER)
    {
        reset();
    }
}

function reset()
{
    score=0;
    RecordSesion=0;
    RecordAbsoluto=0;
    dir=DERECHA;
    body.length=0;
    body.push(new Rectangle(40,40,10,10,"#0f0"));
    body.push(new Rectangle(0,0,10,10,"#0f0"));
    body.push(new Rectangle(0,0,10,10,"#0f0"));
    food.x=random(canvas.width/10-1)*10;
    food.y=random(canvas.height/10-1)*10;
    lastPress=null; 
    gameover=false;
}

function paint(lienzo){
    var gradiente=lienzo.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,canvas.height);
    gradiente.addColorStop(0.5, '#0000FF');
    gradiente.addColorStop(1, '#000000');
    lienzo.fillStyle=gradiente;
    lienzo.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    for(var i=0;i<body.length;i++)
    {
        lienzo.drawImage(medios['iBody'], body[i].x, body[i].y);
    }

    lienzo.drawImage(medios['iFood'], food.x, food.y);

    for(var i=0,l=wall.length;i<l;i++)
    {
        lienzo.drawImage(medios['iWall'], wall[i].x, wall[i].y);
    }

    lienzo.fillStyle="#0f0";
    lienzo.fillText('Score: '+score,10,10);
    lienzo.fillText('RecordSesion: '+score,10,20);
    lienzo.fillText('RecordAbsoluto: '+RecordAbsoluto,10,30);

    if (isStorage && localStorage.getItem('RecordAbsoluto')){
        elements.scores=localStorage.getItem('RecordAbsoluto');
    }

    if(pause || gameover)
    {
        lienzo.textAlign='center';
        if(gameover)
            lienzo.fillText('GAME OVER',150,75);
        else
            lienzo.fillText('PAUSE',150,75);
        lienzo.textAlign='left';
    }
}

function Rectangle(x,y,width,height,color)
{
    this.x=(x==null)?0:x;
    this.y=(y==null)?0:y;
    this.width=(width==null)?0:width;
    this.height=(height==null)?this.width:height;
    this.color = (color==null)?"#000":color;
}

Rectangle.prototype.intersects=function(rect)
{
    if(rect!=null)
    {
        return  (this.x<rect.x+rect.width&&
                this.x+this.width>rect.x&&
                this.y<rect.y+rect.height&&
                this.y+this.height>rect.y);
    }
}

Rectangle.prototype.fill=function(lienzo)
{
    if(lienzo!=null)
    {
        lienzo.fillStyle=this.color;
        lienzo.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
    }
}

Rectangle.prototype.drawImage=function(lienzo, img)
{
    if(img.width)
        lienzo.drawImage(img,this.x,this.y);
    else
        lienzo.strokeRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame=(function()
{
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
        function(callback)
        {
            window.setTimeout(callback,17);
        };
})(); 

function canPlayOgg()
{
    var aud=new Audio();

    if(aud.canPlayType('audio/ogg').replace(/no/,''))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

Array.longitud = function(obj)
{
      return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length - 1;
}

function random(max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*max);
}

window.addEventListener("load", iniciar, false);
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt)
{
    lastPress=evt.keyCode;
}, false);
```

Comment: For all time record you likely need some sort of server with a database behind it to save and update the record

Comment: As far as i know the teacher just wants us to use the localStorage property, not a database.

Comment: Well then what exactly are the problems you having? You are never setting anything in localStorage

Comment: Thats why i need help,because i dont know how to do it.

Comment: localStorage.setItem use it to update the highscore with element.scores whenever a new highscore is made

Comment: Same way with session storage i imagine?

Comment: yep, same way...

Comment: Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).